# I think I misspelled a props,but I am not sure

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So basically,I try to implement React Hooks in my project ,but it gives me this error.
Maybe I am blind and not see the problem, I think I misspelled something.
But maybe i passed wrong props, Im kinda confused now.

This is my sign is component:

```
   const SignIn = ({ emailSignInStart, googleSignInStart }) => {
  const [userCredentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: '',
    passowrd: ''
  });
  const { email, password } = userCredentials;

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailSignInStart(email, password);
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setCredentials({ ...userCredentials, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className='sign-in'>
      <h2>I already have an account</h2>
      <span>Sign in with your email and passowrd</span>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          name='email'
          type='email'
          value={email}
          required
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label='email'
        />

        <FormInput
          name='password'
          type='password'
          value={password}
          required
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label='password'
        />
        <div className='buttons'>
          <CustomButton type='submit'>Sign in</CustomButton>
          <CustomButton
            type='button'
            onClick={googleSignInStart}
            isGoogleSignIn
          >
            Sign in with Google
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  googleSignInStart: () => dispatch(googleSignInStart()),
  emailSignInStart: (email, passowrd) =>
    dispatch(emailSignInStart({ email, passowrd }))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);
```

And This is my form input component:

```
  const FormInput = ({ handleChange, label, ...props }) => (
  <div className='group'>
    <input className='form-input' onChange={handleChange} {...props}></input>
    {label ? (
      <label
        className={`${props.value.length ? 'shrink' : ''} form-input-label`}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
    ) : null}
  </div>
);

export default FormInput;
```

Can somebody help me please with this problem?

Comment: Now, what do you want? Are you facing any issue with your task? If you are then please display the error as well.

Comment: const [userCredentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: '',
    passowrd: ''
  }); passowrd should be password?

Comment: Omg,yeah, password is misspelled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the line:

```
const [userCredentials, setCredentials] = useState({ email: '', passowrd: '' });
```

`passowrd` should be `password`. Otherwise, `userCredentials.password` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for edit recommendation, I formatted it all as code, hope that's also readable :)

Comment: Ok people it's quite the straight forward response, let's stay cool here, 3 edits already just for formatting... lmao

Comment: Feel free to revert the change if you feel it doesn't add to the answer, or changes your intent :) I just added some changes for clarity 

Comment: Previous changes I changed to be more fitting/reverted, but I think yours at least adds some additional clarity that may make it more noob friendly to understand... :)